# Google Friend Connect button stopped working

Tags: google-friend-connect

In my site, I have a button that I and my users used to  connect to GFC.

Now the button is still there, but clicking it does nothing - no response - not even a Javascript error.

Has something changed in the API recently?

Here is the code I use to create the page with button - it's very simple:

```
<body>
<div id='gfclogin' class='login'>
    <a href='#' onclick='google.friendconnect.requestSignIn();'>Connect</a>
</div>
...

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('friendconnect', '0.8');
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>    
    google.friendconnect.container.setParentUrl('/');
    google.friendconnect.container.loadOpenSocialApi({
        site: '11268733983612202568',
        onload: function() {
                if (!window.timesloaded) {
                    window.timesloaded = 1;
                } else {
                    window.timesloaded++;
                }
                if (window.timesloaded > 1) {
                    location.href = location.href.replace(/[&amp;]?to=logout/,'');;
                }
        }});
    google.friendconnect.renderSignInButton({'id': 'gfclogin', 'text': 'Connect', 'style': 'long' });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Friend Connect was deprecated last year](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/more-spring-cleaning-out-of-season.html). It doesn't really exist anymore.

Comment: Wow, that's sad. What is the simplest replacement you can suggest? I only need a simple way to let users login with their Google account.

Comment: OK, I switched to OpenID. Thank you!

Comment: The simplest solution is probably the [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/).